# what is numpy.ndarray without column in python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, size

I saw this sample:

```
from sklearn import cross_validation
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn import datasets
iris = datasets.load_iris()
clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=1)
predicted = cross_validation.cross_val_predict(clf, iris.data,iris.target, cv=10)
metrics.accuracy_score(iris.target, predicted)
```

So I wrote:

```
from sklearn import cross_validation
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn import svm
clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=1)
train_data_input=train_df.iloc[:,1:].values
train_data_output=train_df[[0]].values
predicted = cross_validation.cross_val_predict(clf, train_data_input,train_data_output, cv=10)
metrics.accuracy_score(train_data_output, predicted)
```

but I got this error:
  IndexError: too many indices for array.

I think, this problem is relate to type of "train_data_output".
whilst I see these types:

```
type(train_data_output)
Out[32]: numpy.ndarray

type(iris.target)
Out[33]: numpy.ndarray
```

But in "Spyder>Variable explorer window" I can see a difference, in "size" column it show that my variable has a column like this (891,1), but in sample variable there isn't any column like this (150,)!!!

```
train_data_input.shape
Out[34]: (891, 12)

train_data_output.shape
Out[35]: (891, 1)

predicted.shape
Out[36]: (150,)

iris.target.shape
Out[37]: (150,)
```

By comment @shanmuga I solve my problem in this way:

```
train_data_output=np.reshape(train_data_output, (891,))
```

But how could I extract a column from a datafram that don't need this command?

Comment: Could you share the values of `train_data_input.shape`, `train_data_output.shape` and `predicted.shape`

Comment: Check if `cross_val_predict` function was executed, if so `predicted.shape` should be the same as `train_data_output.shape`. It looks like `predicted` is still holding values from previous calculations on iris data set